# Excel - take product of a range of cells subtracted from 1

Tags: excel

Sorry I am really bad at excel, and couldn't find anything about mapping a range of values to another range. More specifically, I have

[image]

where the Reduction(cm,risk) values for all cm are in a range of cells.
Is there a concise way to do this without creating a new column?

I tried =PRODUCT(1 - C4:C14) but this doesnt work because 1 is not a range.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not too clear, but I guess you first want to subtract 1 from all values in the range `C4:C14` and then do product. If my guess is right then try the same formula you mentioned in the question:

```
=PRODUCT(1-C4:C14)
```

but as an array formula by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>.